# Pandas Error: object of type 'float' has no len()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types, error-handling

I am doing an Pandas exercise in which i need to do the following: Complete the function to clean a specified column in a dataframe by removing non-numeric characters, filling missing values with 0, and transforming the data type to a float.
The code i wrote is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import regex as re
def clean_price_column(df, column):

    df['price'] = df['price'].astype(str).str.extract('(\d+)', expand = False)
    df['price'] = df.price.astype(float)
    df['price'] = df['price'].fillna(0)
    
    solution = df
    return solution
test_case = clean_price_column(prices_df, 'price')
```

I am getting the right result but getting an error which i stated above, how can i fix it?

Comment: Hello, could provide a few example rows from 'price' column of your dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def clean_price_column(df, column):
    df[column] = df[column].astype(str).str.extract(r'(\d+)', expand = False)
    df[column] = df[column].fillna(0)
    df[column] = df[column].astype(float)
    return df

# specify test data
data = {"price": ['$1234', '', 100, '200', None, np.nan, 'txt']}

# create pandas dataframe
prices_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# apply function to pandas dataframe column
prices_df_updated = clean_price_column(prices_df, 'price')

prices_df_updated
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: Nop, still getting the same error :(

Comment: Please provide example data from 'price' column of your dataset in order to check what your issue is related with.